# Comparing arrival rate distributions

Tags: r, distributions

Given two samples of arrival rate of a process (they should end up something like a Poisson distribution):

- One over a long period (something like several days)
- Another from a shorter period time (maybe 30 minutes)

How can I compare the shorter distribution to see if it varies significantly from the longer distribution? Ideally using an existing function in R?

I believe a Q-Q Plot is showing this visually, but I am looking for a single number that would represent how far the shorter sample is from the longer sample.

Also, perhaps better suited for another question. I am a bit curious about how I might say what amount of time would be a representative sample for the longer period of time.

For reference the longer period plot looks something like the following, but it might very somewhat as I decide which attributes I might want to filter out:

[image]

Comment: (Please be gentile, I am aware of my need to spend more time on the basics :-P )

Comment: Poking at this problem, I think how to normalize the X axis on a non-standard distribution will be a component of this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The ks.test (Kolmogorov-Smirnov test) function in R will return a p-value for a two-sample test of the null hypothesis that x and y were drawn from the same continuous distribution, where x and y are would be your two samples.  However, if the number of observations in the shorter data set is small, the test will have very little power, i.e., ability to identify situations where the underlying distributions are actually different.

I assume your second question refers to the sample size needed to generate a representative sample?  This depends upon the arrival process itself and upon your criterion for "representative."  If the arrival process is indeed Poisson, the distribution is characterized by the mean, so the criterion would, in effect, be how accurately you can estimate the mean of the process.  Given a rough estimate of the mean and the criterion, you can calculate an estimate of the sample size necessary to achieve whatever accuracy you want.

Maybe you could expand on this question?

Comment: For now I guess forget about the representative sample aspect. I basically want to be able to take two these distributions, normalize them in the sense that the actual frequency counts (y-axis) and the values of the x-axis don't matter in an absolute sense, and determine if they are the same shape. (I imagine you want to shoot me for describing this as a picture :-P ). So a number that would say something like "The sample has a dip, or a spike, a long tail, etc. The number wouldn't really have to describe what it is, just an estimate of degree.

Comment: In short it would tell me if the sample arrival process is "strange"

Comment: Just to clarify: do you have interarrival times or frequency counts of arrivals over time periods of fixed length?  And many statisticians use pictures to describe statistical phenomena, so don't worry about it!

Comment: It "is frequency counts of arrivals over time periods of fixed length", in my case it is per second.

Comment: In that case, the ks.test is probably not your best bet, because it assumes your underlying distributions are continuous.  Several more questions... Have you characterized the distributions by mean and variance?  Are you observing high counts (e.g., > 5) for the bulk of the frequencies, with some low-count frequencies out in the right tail of the distribution?  Are you interested in comparing to the Poisson, or just to the larger sample?

Comment: For the mean and variance, that is where the need to normalize comes in I think. Depending on the time of the day, the whole thing will shift to the right and expand a little bit during busy times.  I figured out how to do the Poisson at one point and it is pretty close but I think it ended up with a slightly longer right tail (So, really just interested in comparing the shorter to the longer).

Comment: Also, added a quick plot to give you a ballpark idea of what the long period distribution might look like (will probably add some filtering though)

Comment: Thanks for the plot.  The Poisson would be visually indistinguishable from a Normal at those high x-axis values.  It almost looks like you have a mixture of two distributions, one with a peak around 190 and the other with a peak around 290.  A problem with very large sample sizes is that you can almost always reject the null hypothesis (because it's almost always false, in reality) unless you increase the level of the test (e.g., from 95% to 99% to 99.9%) as the sample size increases.  Have you tried overlaying plots of the two cumulative density functions?

Comment: Wikipedia states "cumulative density function" means two things (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_density_function) Can you clarify which one you mean? Not trying to be pedantic, many people probably know which you mean, I'm just actually not sure :-P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1901/discussion-between-jbowman-and-kyle-brandt)